# Is it possible to install both objective c and swift library with Cocoapods in same project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

i want to use both charts [(danielgindi/Charts)](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) written in Swift and Material Components [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) written in Objc in my objective C project.

i done following steps to add both libraries

```
target 'chart4' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for chart4

  pod 'Charts'
```

executed command `pod install`

i opened pod file removed `pod 'Charts'` and commented `use_frameworks!`

```
target 'chart4' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
   #use_frameworks!

  # Pods for chart4
 pod 'MaterialComponents'
```

executed command `pod update` but it resulted in automatic removal of `Charts`. i got following response

```
Analyzing dependencies
Removing Charts
Downloading dependencies
Installing MDFTextAccessibility (1.2.0)
Installing MaterialComponents (34.0.1)
Installing MotionAnimator (1.1.0)
Installing MotionInterchange (1.0.1)
Installing MotionTransitioning (3.2.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 5 total pods installed.
```

Is it possible to install with cocoapod both charts [(danielgindi/Charts)](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) written in Swift and Material Components [Material Components](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) in Same project ?

My Second doubt: Is `pod update` is the correct method to add new pod to project which already have existing pods.

Today i add pod 'AFNetworking' , tommorrow i remove 'AFNetworking' (only from pod file not project) add 'SDWebImage' run pod update . 3 days later i i remove 'SDWebImage' (only from pod file not project) add 'Charts'. Is `pod update` the way to acheive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this and do `pod install`, you do not need to remove pod 'Charts'

```
target 'chart4' do

  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks

   use_frameworks!

      # Pods for chart4

  pod 'Charts'

  pod 'MaterialComponents'
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply . i didn't remove Charts pod it got removed after editing the pod file running pod update ,please reread question. Is it possible to install pods in multiple steps ( i add one pod  today , adds new pod  after twodays) rather than a single step with multiple pod files .

Comment: I have been using only a single pod file, don't know if we could multiple files, you can add pods to the same file and do pod update or pod install to install them whenever you want them

Comment: If you just don't want to install them all at once but to the written there for convenience then you can write pod 'YourPod' and comment the line by just putting a # before it

Comment: i also meant same file . today i add pod 'AFNetworking' , tommorrow i remove 'AFNetworking' (only from pod file not project) add 'SDWebImage' run pod update . 3 days later i i remove 'SDWebImage' (only from pod file not project) add 'Charts'. Is pod update the way to acheive it?

Comment: i think no whenever you remove a pod from pod file and do pod install or pod update then that removed pod will be removed from the project

Comment: i am newbie in iOS, so basically what you are saying is we can't add a single pod we discovered after one month or two month alone . we have to append new single pod to existing multiple pod in file and re install all pods?

Comment: yes reinstalling by pod install only downloads the added pods while pod update checks and update all of them also installing the added pods